# How to calculate a sum for all levels of a a hierarchy

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I want to get the Space-Usage for each database and the sum of all children, grandchildren...

In Teradata the databases are organized in a hierarchy, along the database and its immediate owner.
Each database has its MaxPerm (=allowed space usage) and CurrentPerm (=what is actually used)

What I have so far is the following:
Doing it in two steps, first flatten out the hierarchy, and then sum it up with `rollup`

```
create volatile table dbHierarchy as
(
    WITH RECURSIVE dbs AS
    (
        SELECT
              cast(databasename AS VARCHAR(500)) AS L0
            , cast('' AS VARCHAR(500)) AS L1
            , cast('' AS VARCHAR(500)) AS L2
            --, cast(null AS VARCHAR(500)) AS L3
            , ownername
            , databasename
            , 0 AS depth
            --, CAST(DatabaseName AS VARCHAR(500)) AS pretty_hierarchy
        FROM DBC.databasesv
        WHERE DatabaseName = 'DBC'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
              L0
            , case when dbs.depth = 0 then dbsv.DatabaseName else dbs.L1  end  as L1
            , case when dbs.depth = 1 then dbsv.DatabaseName else dbs.L2  end  as L2
            --,case when dbs.depth = 2 then dbsv.DatabaseName else dbs.L3  end  as L3
            , dbsv.ownername
            , dbsv.databasename
            , depth + 1 AS depth
            --, pretty_hierarchy || substring('            ' FROM 1 FOR (dbs.depth + 1)*3) ||'>'|| dbsv.DatabaseName  as pretty_hierarchy
        FROM dbs
        INNER JOIN "DBC".DatabasesV dbsv
            ON dbsv.OwnerName = dbs.databasename
            AND dbsv.DatabaseName <> dbs.databasename
        WHERE dbs.depth <=10
    )
    SELECT * FROM dbs
) WITH DATA
PRIMARY INDEX (databasename)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

select
      coalesce(L0,'sum') as L0
    , coalesce(L1,'sum') as L1
    , coalesce(L2,'sum') as L2
    --, coalesce(L3,'sum') as L3
    ,SUM(Space.MaxPerm)/(1024*1024)(bigint)  as Max_Perm
    ,SUM(Space.CurrentPerm)/(1024*1024) (bigint) as Current_Perm
from DBC.DiskSpace Space
    inner join dbHierarchy Hir
    on Space.databasename = Hir.databasename
    group by rollup (L0,L1,L2) --(L0, L1,L2,L3)
    order by L0, L1, L2 --, L3
;
```

That is fine so far, but somehow restricted by the fixed number of levels.
I can customize it for the actual use case (adding level according to the actual depth of the found hierarchy).

Is there a different approach, which adapts itself to the depth in the hierarchy?

The actual output is

```
sum;sum;sum;37780;301
DBC;sum;sum;37780;301
DBC;;sum;34369;125
DBC;;;34369;125
DBC;All;sum;0;0
DBC;All;;0;0
DBC;Crashdumps;sum;71;0
DBC;Crashdumps;;71;0
...
DBC;Samples;sum;1215;159
DBC;Samples;;9;0
DBC;Samples;financial;12;11
DBC;Samples;manufacturing;0;0
DBC;Samples;retail;22;21
DBC;Samples;sandbox;1024;0
DBC;Samples;tpch;52;46
DBC;Samples;transportation;0;0
DBC;Samples;twm_md;76;70
DBC;Samples;twm_results;4;0
DBC;Samples;twm_source;11;9
...
DBC;SysAdmin;sum;1043;2
DBC;SysAdmin;;19;2
DBC;SysAdmin;user1;1024;0
```

which is ok. I get the sum for user1 and for Samples. But if I add a level, lets say with additional databases owned by user1, I have to add an additional level. Adding the level or concatenated databasenames doesn't work in the rollup (at least I didn't get it to work). I want the sum for each name in that level.

The ultimate target is to have an overview of space usage by groups, which are placed on different levels within the hierarchy. And the SQL should still work if user1 is moved to DBC->GroupSpace->Group7->Project1->Subproject5->SandBox.
And I want to be able to answer questions about overall and detailed space usage within Group7

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you want?  My suspicion is that you should put the output on separate rows rather than separate columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dbc.ChildrenV` resolves the hierachy to one row per `parent/child`, this is what I use for calculating Current/MaxPerm for all databases and their children:

```
WITH DBSpace AS 
 ( -- PermSpace for each database
   SELECT
      DatabaseName
     ,Sum(MaxPerm) AS MaxPerm
     ,Sum(CurrentPerm) AS CurrentPerm
   FROM dbc.DiskSpaceV
   GROUP BY DatabaseName
 )
SELECT
   DBSpace.DatabaseName
  ,DBSpace.MaxPerm
  ,DBSpace.CurrentPerm
  ,ChildSpace.ChildrenCount
  ,ChildSpace.ChildrenMaxPerm
  ,ChildSpace.ChildrenCurrentPerm
  ,DBSpace.CurrentPerm + Coalesce(ChildSpace.ChildrenCurrentPerm,0)
FROM DBSpace
LEFT JOIN
 ( -- PermSpace for all children of a database
   SELECT
      ch.Parent
     ,Sum(sp.MaxPerm) AS ChildrenMaxPerm
     ,Sum(sp.CurrentPerm) AS ChildrenCurrentPerm
     ,Count(*)
        -- 4 rows (all/dbc/default/public) for parent = dbc are missing in dbc.Children:
      + CASE WHEN ch.Parent = 'dbc' THEN 4 ELSE 0 END AS ChildrenCount
   FROM
      dbc.ChildrenV AS ch 
   JOIN DBSpace AS sp
     ON ch.Child = sp.DatabaseName
   GROUP BY ch.Parent
 ) AS ChildSpace
ON DBSpace.DatabaseName = ChildSpace.Parent
-- uncomment to return only databases with PermSpace
-- WHERE ChildrenMaxPerm > 0 OR MaxPerm > 0;
```

You can join this to a recursive query to display the hierarchy in correct order (`EXTUSER` will be missing, but this is just a dummy):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (DatabaseName, Path, LEVEL) AS
 (
   SELECT Trim(DatabaseName)
          ,DatabaseName(VARCHAR(600))
          ,0 (BYTEINT)
   FROM   dbc.DatabasesV AS d
   WHERE  DatabaseName = 'dbc'

   UNION ALL

   SELECT Trim(d.DatabaseName)
          ,cte.Path || '.' || Trim(d.DatabaseName)
          ,LEVEL + 1
   FROM   dbc.DatabasesV AS d
          ,cte
   WHERE  d.OwnerName = cte.DatabaseName
   AND    d.DatabaseName <> d.OwnerName
   AND    LEVEL < 20
 )
,DBSpace AS 
 ( -- PermSpace for each database
   SELECT
      DatabaseName
     ,Sum(MaxPerm) AS MaxPerm
     ,Sum(CurrentPerm) AS CurrentPerm
   FROM dbc.DiskSpaceV
   GROUP BY DatabaseName
 )
SELECT LEVEL
       ,Substring(Cast('' AS CHAR(60)) FROM 1 FOR LEVEL * 2)  || cte.DatabaseName AS Hierarchy
       ,AllSpaces.*
FROM cte JOIN 
 (
   SELECT
      DBSpace.DatabaseName
     ,DBSpace.MaxPerm
     ,DBSpace.CurrentPerm
     ,Coalesce(ChildSpace.ChildrenCount, 0) AS ChildrenCount
     ,ChildSpace.ChildrenMaxPerm
     ,ChildSpace.ChildrenCurrentPerm
   FROM DBSpace
   LEFT JOIN
    ( -- PermSpace for all children of a database
      SELECT
         ch.Parent
        ,Sum(sp.MaxPerm) AS ChildrenMaxPerm
        ,Sum(sp.CurrentPerm) AS ChildrenCurrentPerm
        ,Count(*)
           -- 4 rows (all/dbc/default/public) for parent = dbc are missing in dbc.Children:
         + CASE WHEN ch.Parent = 'dbc' THEN 4 ELSE 0 END AS ChildrenCount
      FROM
         dbc.ChildrenV AS ch 
      JOIN DBSpace AS sp
        ON ch.Child = sp.DatabaseName
      GROUP BY ch.Parent
    ) AS ChildSpace
   ON DBSpace.DatabaseName = ChildSpace.Parent
 ) AS AllSpaces
  ON cte.DatabaseName = AllSpaces.DatabaseName
-- uncomment to return only databases with PermSpace
-- WHERE ChildrenMaxPerm > 0 OR MaxPerm > 0
ORDER BY Path;
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. :-)